# No footnotemark in the listoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, footnotes

I'd like to have footnotes in the caption of listings. I got that working. But the `\footnotemark` gets shown in the `\listoflistings`. Normally you can specificly define the text for a caption for the listofXY. But this does not work as I have to give the caption inside of squared brackets. So I cannot use the squared brackets (which usually define the title for the listofXY) here.

Some example code which works:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={myCaption\protect\footnotemark},label=myLabel]
    // code
\end{lstlisting}
\footnotetext{The text for the footnote}
```

Does anyone of you have an idea, how I can modify this code snippet to prevent the `\footnotemark` to be shown in the `\listoflistings`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547617/no-footnotemark-in-the-listoflistings?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward hack:

```
{
\let\footnotemark\relax
\lstlistoflistings
}
```

This redefines the `\footnotemark` macro to do nothing within the scope of the list of listings.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly I was looking for.
Putting this around my whole appendix is a nicer solution than the alternative caption for the listings inside the [squared brackets]